# ZMQ_ROUTER Semantics: Dropping Disconnected Peers

Tags: c++, zeromq

I wanted to develop a reliable multi-client, single-server req/rep communication pattern. I decided to use ZMQ_REQ and ZMQ_ROUTER sockets in order to accomplish this task.

The ZeroMQ RFC states the following:

> The ROUTER socket type SHALL create a double queue when a peer
> connects to it. If this peer disconnects, the ROUTER socket SHALL
> destroy its double queue and SHALL discard any messages it contains.

According to this semantics I expect messages ROUTER to drop disconnected clients. I developed the following code to test my design.

```
// Client Code
// cppzmq: v4.10.0
// libzmq: v4.3.5
#include <zmq.hpp>
#include <iostream>

zmq::context_t context{1};

bool reqrep(zmq::message_t &req, std::string addr)
{
    zmq::socket_t client{context, zmq::socket_type::req};
    client.set(zmq::sockopt::rcvtimeo, 2500);
    client.set(zmq::sockopt::sndtimeo, 2500);
    client.set(zmq::sockopt::immediate, true);
    client.set(zmq::sockopt::linger, 0);

    client.connect(addr);
    if (!client.send(req))
    {
        std::cerr << "E: send timeout\n";
        return false;
    }

    zmq::message_t rep;
    if (client.recv(rep))
    {
        std::cout << "I: server replied OK (" << rep.to_string() << ")\n";
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cerr << "E: receive timeout\n";
        return false;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::string addr{"ipc:///tmp/server"};

    int seq{};
    while (true)
    {
        zmq::message_t req{std::to_string(seq++)};
        reqrep(req, addr);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

```
// Server Code
// cppzmq: v4.10.0
// libzmq: v4.3.5

#include <unistd.h>
#include <zmq_addon.hpp>
#include <iostream>

//  Provide random number from 0..(num-1)
#define within(num) (int)((float)((num) * random()) / (RAND_MAX + 1.0))

int main()
{
    zmq::context_t context(1);
    zmq::socket_t server(context, ZMQ_ROUTER);

    server.bind("ipc:///tmp/server");

    while (1)
    {
        zmq::multipart_t mp;
        auto req = zmq::recv_multipart(server, std::back_inserter(mp));
        std::cout << "I: message received";
        std::cout << mp.str() << std::endl;
        if (!within(20))
        {
            std::cout << "I: simulating CPU overload" << std::endl;
            sleep(20);
        }
        sleep(1); // Do work
        zmq::send_multipart(server, mp);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The results doesn't satify my expectations (left: server, right: client). After 20 seconds of sleep, server still keeps the messages from the disconnected peers and processes them.
[image: left: server, right: client]

Is there something I miss? I will be looking for feedbacks.

Answer (score 1):

The connections are managed asynchronously in the zeromq context threads so unless you call `disconnect` on the client or `unbind` on the server (or there is a real network issue) no disconnects will happen.

You can investigate further with `socket_monitor`

https://libzmq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/zmq_socket_monitor.html

Comment: Thanks for `socket_monitor` suggestion. In the destructor of `zmq::socket_t` cppzmq calls `close` on the zmq socket. That destructor is called at the end of `reqrep` function and client sockets are closed. Doesn't a socket disconnect when it's closed gracefully?

Comment: If I use TCP as the transport layer, I'm able to observe connection is terminated after each `reqrep` with the help of wireshark.

Comment: I also tried by adding `disconnect` statement to the end of `reqrep` function but the result didn't change.

Answer (score 0):

To extend James Harvey's answer, and just in case you are running on Linux (specifically, Linux), there's a neat trick you can do. And, have you come across this because you were simply ctrl-c'ing the client (or other equivalent instant process termination like exit(), return from main(), etc)?

The the answers are "no" and "no", read no further!

On Linux you can use `signalfd` as a means for signals to be delivered to your process and handled without resorting to signal handler routines. The idea is that you can set up `signalfd` to capture specified signals, and you get information about them delivered through a file descriptor. The nice thing about this - especially with ZeroMQ - is that you can include the `signalfd` file descriptor in a call to `zmq_poll()`.

If you do set this up for ctrl-c, of hang-up, or any other signal, you can choose what to do about them at leisure in the program's main loop that's calling `zmq_poll()`. For instance, I'll have it set to capture ctrl-c, and when that is delivered my programs will typically kick off whatever it is that is required to "finish", usually culminating in calls to `zmq_close()`, etc, and finally cleaning up the zmq context.

That way anything that ZMQ is going to do to clean up the connection to something else (perhaps sending a zmtp packet to tell the remote to drop the connection) can happen, and things become a lot less confusing.

`Signalfd` is AFAIK a purely Linux thing. Other OSes may have their own way of achieving the same effect. I consider `signalfd` to be the sole way any new code should deal with signals, finally getting rid of the tyranny of signal handlers and their limitations and complications.